# Do a thing when there is a specific error

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch

**I want to let my program do something when i have this error:** **`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "lekker hoor"`**. Can someone help me with this?

**I want to let it open a Joptionpane when this error happens whit the text:** *`Dont use letters or spaces. Only use numbers.`*

Comment: try catch ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Comment: Have you looked online at all? Try looking into something like: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: There u can find another solution [stackoverflow.com::how to check if a string is numeric in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Use try catch block:

```
try {
  //your code....
} catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
  // Open your JOptionPane Here
}
```

Comment: Don't catch `Exception` unless something in the try block actually throws `Exception` specifically.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah. Thanks. I did put that because if he has any other exceptions to catch. But it was misleading. __Edited__ now.